# How can I find the exact version of DirectX installed?

Tags: directx

I've installed the directx_Jun2010_redist.exe from Microsoft. On the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b170b25-abab-4bc3-ae91-50ceb6d8fa8d) it states it's version is Version:9.29.1962.

However when I check with dxdiag, it writes that "DirectX-version: DirectX9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)" But why is it 4.09.xx when I just installed 9.29.xxxx?

Strangely, there is a newer version of DirectX with [webinstaller](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3) only, which is Version:9.29.1973. But when I try to install, it says that a newer or equivalent version is already installed.

Is there any way to find out exactly which version of directX is installed on my computer?

In other words How can I determine which version of directX is installed on an unknown computer? How can I find out if it is 9.28.1886 (Febr 2010) or 9.27.1734 (Aug 2009) or the latest 9.29.1962 (June 2010) version?

Comment: = Are you using xp or windows 7?

Comment: sry, I'm using XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction: How does the version numbering work?

See [Wikipedia - Microsoft Version Numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_version_numbering) although they seem to have used shorter formats too:

**Major/Minor Version Numbering**
`A.BB`

**Installer Version Numbering**
`A.BB.CCCC`

**Software Version Numbering**
`A.BB.CCCC.DDDD`

With `A` = Major Feature, `BB` = Minor Feature, `CCCC` = Major Build, `DDDD` = Minor Build.

So, when major or minor features are added the whole version number will update.
All other less important changes will only update the build, which brings us to a rule for customers...

### Check the major/minor version info, not the installer or software build!

Customers should check the version number, not the build number to determine if they have the latest.

For Windows XP, **the latest version supported by the OS is 9.0c**.

It doesn't matter if you take the offline or the web installer, they will result in the same version.

### Then why are the build numbers different?

Because **the installer has been rewritten** because people where in need of an easier web install.

The build numbers differ by more than 1 because there were internal test versions in between.

The version shown in DirectX doesn't include the installer and thus differs from the one visible to you.

### Let's compare:

The offline version is 9.29.1962, the web version is 9.29.1973. Both are 9.0c.

It's reasonable to have around 4 alpha builds, 4 beta builds, 1 release build and the release itself.
In this small amount of installer builds, not much would have been changed.

This is why **an equivalent version is detected, because DirectX itself hasn't been changed.**

Comment: Thanks for the information about directx but will this solve the problem of csadam. He is having problem in installing directx and he wants to  which version of directx has been installed in his computer.

Comment: If you have read what I said you would know **he already has the last version**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. Probably my question is not clear enough. My problem is that I cant find the version number of the installed DirectX in windows. The dxdiag writes 4.09... which is pretty irrelevant. Let's say I have an unknown computer and I want to check what version of directX is installed on that. What do have I to do to find out the version number?

Comment: @csadam: As I said, **don't read the extended build number**, but just **9.0c**: http://imageshare.web.id/images/p98xtp203r54hpk3ggm1.jpg ;-)

Comment: I understand that, but :)  The Febr 2010 update was 9.0c as well, wasn't it? How can I tell which update is installed?

Comment: @csadam: Sorry, but you are repeating yourself, **9.0c** in installed as shown in your DxDiag (see the picture of my last comment where you need to look). As for Febr 2010, it might be that they have combined multiple versions into an installer to ease the installation. It will automatically install the best version for your system...

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the offline version of directx and then install it. since after seeing this question I also installed this june2010 directx and it installed without any problem.
 You just use ccleaner and clean your your pc and try to install directx again if installing from offline fails.
Reply me.

offline site:http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b170b25-abab-4bc3-ae91-50ceb6d8fa8d

Comment: No need for a re-install, check my answer, his DirectX is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks, but my directX is running fine. My problem is that I can't determine which version is installed. Ok, I think it's the latest, because I used the latest installer. 
But where can I find its version number in my windows?